# help porting unix commands to perl script

Tags: perl

I am getting some perl compile errors trying to convert these unix commands to perl. 
The use of single quotes and double quotes is throwing me off (see below: `my $curlcmd`).

Here's the **working** unix commands executed in order:

```
export CERT=`/dev/bin/util --show dev.testaccnt | awk '{print $2}'`

/usr/bin/curl -c /home/foobar/cookee.txt --certify /dev/key.crt \
     --header "FooBar-Util:'${CERT}'" \
     https://devhost.foobar.com:4443/fs/workflow/data/source/productname?val=Summ
```

I want to do the same within **Perl**:

```
#Build cmd in perl
my $cookie='/home/foobar/cookee.txt';
my $certkey='/dev/key.crt';
my $fsProxyHostPort='devhost.foobar.com:4443';
my $fsPath='workflow/data/source/productname';
my $fsProxyOperation='Summ';
my $fsProxyURL="https://$fsProxyHostPort/fs/$fsPath?val=$fsProxyOperation";

#Get cert
my $cert=qx(/dev/bin/pass-util --show foobar.dev.testaccnt | awk '{print \$2}');
```

Here's where I am having trouble executing it:

```
my $curlcmd = qx(/usr/bin/curl -c $cookie --certify $certkey --header "FooBar-Util:'${" . $cert . "}'". $fsProxyURL);
```

Can someone show me how to setup these commands in Perl correctly?

Comment: It is extremely aconventional to have executables or data files under `/dev`; that directory is for devices (such as `/dev/null`, `/dev/tty`) and should not normally be modified by users, nor would you normally create sub-directories and put commands in it.  Its name is not an abbreviation for `development`.

Comment: you are right. for the sake of posting my example, i should have used `/devel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the shell script, you have (in part):

```
--header "FooBar-Util:'${CERT}'"
```

This generates something like:

```
--header FooBar-Util:'data-from-certificate'
```

where the `curl` command gets to see those single quotes. To get the same result in Perl, you will need:

```
my $header = "FooBar-Util:'$cert'";
my $out = qx(/usr/bin/curl -c $cookie --certify $certkey --header $header $fsProxyURL);
```

Changes:

- Lost the `${ ... }` notation.
- Lost the concatenation operations.

In situations where you have problems seeing the argument list sent to a command, I recommend using a program analogous to the shell `echo` command, but which lists each argument on its own line, rather than as a space-separated set of arguments on a single line.  I call my version of this `al` for 'argument list'.  If you test your commands (for example, the shell version) by prefixing the whole command line with `al`, you get to see the arguments that `curl` would see.  You can then do the same in Perl to compare the arguments `curl` sees at the shell with the ones given it by Perl.  Then you can fix the problems, typically much more easily.

For debugging with `al`:

```
my @lines = qx(al /usr/bin/curl -c $cookie --certify $certkey --header $header $fsProxyURL);
foreach my $line (@lines) { print "$line"; }
```

---

If you want to write `al` in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
foreach my $arg (@ARGV) { print "$arg\n"; }
```

---

#### Adventures in Validating an Answer

Fortunately, I usually check what I write as answers - and what is written above is mostly accurate, except for one detail; Perl manages to invoke the shell on the command, and in doing so, the shell cleans out the single-quotes:

```
my $cert = 'certificate-info';
my $fsProxyURL = 'https://www.example.com/fsProxy';
my $cookie = 'cookie';
my $certkey = 'cert-key';
my $header = "FooBar-Util:'$cert'";
#my @out = qx(al /usr/bin/curl -c $cookie --certify $certkey --header $header $fsProxyURL);
my @cmdargs = ( 'al', '/usr/bin/curl', '-c', $cookie, '--certify', $certkey, '--header', $header, $fsProxyURL);
print "System:\n";
system @cmdargs;
print "\nQX command:\n";
my @lines = qx(@cmdargs);
foreach my $line (@lines) { print "$line"; }
```

This yields:

```
System:
/usr/bin/curl
-c
cookie
--certify
cert-key
--header
FooBar-Util:'certificate-info'
https://www.example.com/fsProxy

QX command:
/usr/bin/curl
-c
cookie
--certify
cert-key
--header
FooBar-Util:certificate-info
https://www.example.com/fsProxy
```

Note the difference in the `FooBar lines!

At this point, you start to wonder what's the least unclean way to work around this.  If you want to use the `qx//` operator, then you probably do:

```
my $header = "FooBar-Util:\\'$cert\\'";
```

This yields the variant outputs (`system` then `qx//`):

```
FooBar-Util:\'certificate-info\'

FooBar-Util:'certificate-info'
```

So, the `qx//` notation now gives the single quotes to the executed command, just as in the shell script.  This meets the goal, so I'm going to suggest that it is 'OK' for you; I'm just not sure that I'd actually adopt it in my own code, but I don't have a cleaner mechanism on hand.  I'd like to be able to use the `system` plus 'array of arguments' mechanism, while still capturing the output, but I haven't checked whether there's a sensible (meaning relatively easy) way to do that.

One other passing comment; if any of your arguments contained spaces, you'd have to be excruciatingly careful with what gets passed through the shell.  Having the `al` command available really pays off then.  You can't identify which spaces in `echo` output are parts of one argument and which are separators provided by `echo`.

Answer (score 1):

Is it on purpose that you have two different definitions of `$cert`?

Your translation of `--header "FooBar-Util:'${CERT}'"` is bad. The `${...}` tells the shell to insert the `CERT` variable, but since you're already doing this insertation from Perl, it is not needed and will just confuse.

You're also missing a space before the `$fsProxyURL`.

As you're apparently not using the captured output from curl for anyting, I would suggest that you use the `system` function instead so you avoid the use of an intermediate shell command line parsing:

```
system "/usr/bin/curl","-c",$cookie,"--certify",$certTheFirst,
       "--header","FooBar-Util:'$certTheSecond'", $fsProxyURL;
```

Finally, it's not very perlish to use a subsidiary awk to split the pass-util value into fields when Perl does that kind of things perfectly well. Once you solve the immediate error, I suggest

```
my @passwordline = split / /, qx(/dev/bin/util --show dev.testaccnt);
my $certTheSecond = $passwordline[1];
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion. i made the edits. one should be `$certkey` and `$cert` would be the command for using the cert utility. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This    `" . $cert . "` seems to be a leftover from some other code, where black-quotes were used and not `qx`. Removing the black-quotes and concatenations (`.`) works on my machine.

So, to execute the command, do:

```
my $curlcmd = qx(/usr/bin/curl -c $cookie --certify $certkey --header "FooBar-Util:'${ $cert }'". $fsProxyURL);
```

---

Following your comment, if you just want  to print the command, you can do:

```
my $curlcmd = qq(/usr/bin/curl -c $cookie --certify $certkey --header "FooBar-Util:'${ $cert  }'". $fsProxyURL);
print $curlcmd;
```

Comment: thanks. if i wanted to print this out to view the output first. Can I just do a print without actually executing it?